# how to bind data as routeValue in telerik ListView template

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

My template modified from MvcMusicStore tutroial:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">
    <div class="product">
    <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Store", new {id = ${ProductSubCategoryId} })">
         <img src="@Url.Content("${AlbumArtUrl}")" alt="${Title} image" />
             </a>
        <span><h3>${Title}</h3></span>

        <p>${kendo.toString(Price, "c")}</p>
    </div>
</script>
```

but there is error in Url.Action method: Unexpected symbol '$'.

Update 1:
And i can't use

```
@Model.First(d => d.ProductCategoryId.Equals(Convert.ToInt32("${ProductSubCategoryId}"))).ProductCategory.Name
```

but same code in

```
@Url.Content("${AlbumArtUrl}")
```

work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new {id = ${ProductSubCategoryId} }`

This is C# code for an anonymous object, and C# doesn't know anything about JS templating.  Hence the error telling you it doesn't know what that $ is doing there.  Usually you'd pass something from your View model, which is only available serverside:

`new {id = Model.ProductSubCategoryId }`

Instead of using a URL helper, you might be better off with just a string `href="Store/Details/${ProductSubCategoryId}"`.  That may not be exactly what you need, but I don't know enough about the routing and your template to know if this is what you intended, or if ProductSubCategoryId is actually a property of your model.

In regards to your updated examples:

`Url.Content(` works because that function takes the parameter as the page is being rendered on the server, and just spits out with the string "${AlbumArtUrl}" in the HTML pretty much as it is, and the HTML will contain the string "${AlbumArtUrl}" so that when the JS template is parsed later on the client, it can interpret that variable.    So in this case, the C# function `.Content(` doesn't need to understand that template variable, because to it, it is just a string that it embeds in the HTML.  I would recommend using F12 in Chrome to view the GET response in the network tab so you can see the HTML source as it was returned from the action, so you have a better idea in your mind of what exactly what is happening at each step of the process.  You'll be able to see that in your HTML returned, there is no C# code like Url.Content, but you will see the javascript template stuff like "${AlbumArtUrl}" because those values aren't rendered on the server side.

On the other hand `Convert.ToInt32("${ProductSubCategoryId}")` fails, because this function expects the string it's being passed to be an integer, such as `Convert.ToInt32("2134")`.  As far as ToInt32 is concerned, it says, ok, I see "something" is a string, now I will try to interpret the string as a number which means I expect it to contain some digits, such as "456457" but you gave me a bunch of letters and symbols which means nothing to me, I can't convert that into an integer.  Again, this is C# function that is running on the server as it generates the page, and "${ProductSubCategoryId}" means nothing to C# as it is a javascript template variable.

Comment: Yes, Url.Action("Details", "Store")/${ProductSubCategoryId} work fine, but it i want to know why i cant use routeValue.

new {id = Model.ProductSubCategoryId } I cant use because of Model is IEnumerable.

Comment: If you are determined to use the server side HTML helper, you would need a `@foreach(var item in Model)` to loop through the items in the model so that you can access `item.ProductSubCategoryId` for each item.  But if I understand what your template is doing, you probably don't need a loop, and instead just give up on using `.ActionLink` since this is a client-side template.

Comment: @TheX also updated answer to address the two examples you added to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing server-side code with client-side code. This is invalid C# code:

```
@Url.Content("${AlbumArtUrl}")
```

You cannot use helper to generate URLs this way. I suggest you to go the normal way without using the Url helper.

Comment: No! This statement work well.
Error in <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Store", new {id = ${ProductSubCategoryId} })"> statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are determined to use Url.Action, then here is a way.  It is a hack but you can do this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Store")?id=${ProductSubCategoryId}">
```